# Can an invader spawn on an edge that leads to an owned room

Tags: screeps

Invaders randomly attack rooms that have a player in them. They seem to spawn on the edge of a room. Can such an invader spawn on an exit that leads to another room where I own the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot. Per the documentation:

> An important feature of these creeps is that they can appear only at
>   **exits to neutral rooms**. If the target room is under your (or someone else’s) control or it is a reserved room, an invader creep will never
>   appear at this exit. If all exits in the room are of this kind,
>   invaders cannot appear at all.

[Source](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/207729055)